# Android Programmatically open Settings-> Security tab on Button Click

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How can I open Android > Settings > Security tab from within my app?

In my app, I have one simple button and I want to open the Security tab setting on button click listener event.

I have tried to open android settings, but how do I open specifically the security one?

Comment: I am not just asking about setting. i am asking about settings->Security.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);

        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: You need to Up-vote the answer if it helped you @Anny :)

Comment: Sorry. I dont have that much reputation for upvote answer as i am new

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
 startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS), 0);
```

When the user hits the back button, your app will open again.